# Using IEnumerable to Union two mocked objects in XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, ienumerable, xunit.net

I am trying to test some logic when creating a new entity. Either:

1. the entity comes in with no associated functionalities (in which case it gets all the existing core functionalities), or
2. the entity comes in with some associated functionalities (in which case it gets those functionalities ∪ all the existing core functionalities).

My setup is like this:

```
// Non-core functionality
var functionality = new Mock<IFunctionality>();
functionality.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());

// Entity with non-core functionality
var entity = new Mock<IEntity>();
entity.Setup(x => x.Functionalities).Returns(new List<IFunctionality>
{
    functionality.Object
});

// Core functionality
var coreFunctionality = new Mock<IFunctionality>();
coreFunctionality.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
coreFunctionality.Setup(x => x.IsCore).Returns(true);

// All functionalities
var functionalities = new List<IFunctionality>
{
    functionality.Object,
    coreFunctionality.Object
};

var functionalityManager = new Mock<IFunctionalityManager<IFunctionality>>();
functionalityManager.Setup(x => x.GetCoreFunctionalities()).Returns(new List<IFunctionality>
{
    coreFunctionality.Object
});

var service = new EntityService<IEntity>(functionalityManager.Object);
```

Then I call:

```
var create = service.Create(entity.Object);
```

The service implements the above logic like this:

```
var coreFunctionalitites = _functionalityManager.GetCoreFunctionalities();
entity.Functionalities = entity.Functionalities != null
    ? entity.Functionalities.Union(coreFunctionalitites).ToList()
    : coreFunctionalitites.ToList();
```

This works as expected in practice (i.e., when posting to the API), but the following assertion always fails when testing:

```
Assert.Equal(functionalities.Count, create.Functionalities.Count);
```

When I debug the test, I can see in the Immediate Window that `coreFunctionalities` does contain `coreFunctionality` (with a Guid):

```
coreFunctionalitites.First()
{Mock<IFunctionality:00000002>.Object}
    Id: {b0bbb77e-3e1a-415b-ac78-c36f1714ecf9}
    IsCore: true
    Mock (Castle.Proxies.IFunctionalityProxy): {Mock<IFunctionality:00000002>}
    Mock: {Mock<IFunctionality:00000002>}
```

I can also hover over `entity.Functionalities` and see that it contains `functionality` (with a separate Guid):

```
{Mock<IFunctionality:00000001>.Object}
    Id: {3c4396d3-9667-418e-9287-da56c529cd90}
    IsCore: false
    Mock (Castle.Proxies.IFunctionalityProxy): {Mock<IFunctionality:00000001>}
    Mock: {Mock<IFunctionality:00000001>}
```

But when I try `entity.Functionalities.First()` in the Immediate Window I get:

```
error CS1061: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Functionalities' and no extension method 'Functionalities' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

After the `Union`, `coreFunctionality` was not added to `entity.Functionalities`. Am I missing something in the setup to make this work?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the relevant method in the service to use the specific `IEntity` interface (to eliminate the generics variable). With that change, I can now successfully view `entity.Functionalities.First()` in the Immediate Windows with no error. But the `Union` still fails.